# Should I detach elements from the DOM while I apply many styles to them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, dom

I'm concerned about performance and best practices.

1. So I'm building graphical UI and learned that I shouldn't call `jQuery.append()` a gazillion times when creating many small elements. So I got that covered by `document.createDocumentFragment()`. I'm adding elements to that, then once done, I insert the fragment to the DOM (with `appendChild`),
2. Then, in another pass I calculate where each element should be. Everything is absolutely positioned and will receive `x` and `y` values via [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform). Unfortunately, for these calculations I need the elements in the DOM since some of them contan random length text, and **I need to measure widht/height**. Otherwise I would perform step 3 on the document fragment directly, before it's even inserted into the DOM.
3. In the final pass I apply the calculated styles over everything with `jQuery.css()` (will likely replace with `setAttribute` instead of jQuery) as part of a loop (many calls to that, unfortunately - every element has different x/y). **Should I detach the container that holds all my elements while I apply the styles**, then reattach it to the DOM?

Comment: It will always be fastest to have html content in the html before page load. Why are you adding content to the DOM later?

Comment: You can use `jQuery.append()` on a container element that is in memory, and then append the container to the DOM once you're done. That way there is only 1 DOM redraw

Comment: "Everything is absolutely positioned" that way lies madness

Comment: Because this part of the UI is worthless without JS. I guess I could print the elements via PHP, but then it would be a royal useless mess of unstyled unpositioned objects if there was no JS enabled (or if JS execution stopped due to an erro). Even my CSS is short. This is all just an enhancement to content, which happens to consist of many lines and shapes. It's not essential to the content itself though. Think of it as a particle system (it's not), but would you still create the particles with PHP?

Comment: I have my reasons @zzzzBov - for example [jQuery masonry](https://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index2.html) has all tiles as absolutely positioned elements. That is a legit use too, I believe.

Comment: To be clear, I'm *not* saying "there is no case where you should absolutely position everything", I'm warning that it's frustrating and likely a bad choice. You probably want to look into grid layout, and you probably want to make use of a rendering engine such as React or Vue because they'll be a lot more useful than jQuery.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have no problem, just asking if it's better to detach while applying a bunch of styles to a number of elements, or if it doesn't matter...

Comment: @zzzzBov it's not a gallery, it has nothing to do with grids. It's an nda project for now so I can't say what it is. Tried to do it with CSS but it's just so proprietary and every single element is different from the other. Though I'll consider printing the elements from PHP, it doesn't change the fact and the scope of my question, how should I proceed when applying the styles.

Comment: "it's not a gallery, it has nothing to do with grids" this makes me believe that you know very little about grid layout, and that you should probably learn more before dismissing it.

Comment: No :) I created [justifiedgrid.com](http://justifiedgrid.com/) so I know a lot about grids :) Trust me what I'm doing is not a grid. Tried CSS flexbox but wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to lack of interest I decided to test it myself. Pulling an element of 700+ articles (15000 nodes), applying various CSS on the majority of them, then putting the element back into the page was actually slower by 50%. Let the browser do its job by only showing the results of changed attributes when Layout is needed.

I read the advice somewhere to remove the element from the DOM while working on it. While this could be true when appending elements to it, this does not hold true for style manipulations.